# Don't allow refresh webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link:

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:isRename();" class="current-text">rename</a>
```

which invokes isRename() function:

```
function isRename(){    
var i = getCheckboxCount(); 
if(i==1){   
    showInputDialog(getCheckboxName(),'Rename', 'Enter the name of file/directory',null);
}   
}

function showInputDialog(a,b,c,okFunc){ 
$.fn.InitInputDialog(a,b,c,okFunc);
$.fn.fadeInCommon(); 
};
```

It shows a modal window. This window has a close button.

```
$("#CloseInputButton").off('click'); //MY CLOSE BUTTON IN MODAL WINDOW      
    $("#CloseInputButton").click(function(){
        fadeOutCommon();            
    }); 

$.fn.fadeOutCommon = function(){        
    //transition effect
    $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.0,function(){
        $(dialogID).hide();     
        $('#mask, .window').hide();
    });
```

};
It works fine before I press the close button. My web page refreshes and fadeOutCommon animation doesn't work at all! I think it happens because of refreshing web page! How can I disable refreshing web page?
Thanks

Comment: You possibly won't need to "disable refresh", as a sidenote: disabling refresh on user's browser is what I would consider offensive and frustrating... Either change your UI design or deal with it.

Comment: `onClick="javascript:isRename();"` <- you're mixing handler syntax with href syntax. `javascript:` shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write down `return false;` will do that task.

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:return isRename();" class="current-text">rename</a>

    function isRename(){     
    var i = getCheckboxCount();  
    if(i==1){        
         showInputDialog(getCheckboxName(),'Rename', 'Enter the name of file/directory',null); }    
    return false;
    }
```

**Also have look to**

`e.preventDefault()` will prevent the default event from occuring, `e.stopPropagation()` will prevent the event from bubbling up and return false will do both.

Comment: I placed "return false;" to everywhere where I can, but result is the same - it doens't work!

Comment: Ok. I'll try it tomorrow and let you know! Thank you.

Comment: How can I get "e"? I tried `onClick="javascript:return isRename(this);"` and in the function `function isRename(e){ e.preventDefault(); .... }` but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

you can put `return false` in your click methods

```
$("#CloseInputButton").click(function(){
    fadeOutCommon();  
 return false;          
});
```